# Borrar registros en sql server

Tags: sql

Tengo el tipo

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[agendas] AS TABLE(
[id0] [int] NOT NULL,
[que] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
[finicio] [date] NOT NULL,
[ffin] [date] NOT NULL,
[importe] [money] NOT NULL,
[descripcion] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
```

En un procedimiento almacenado hago

```
update dbo.[eventos publico] set nombre=que,finicio=o.finicio,ffin=o.ffin,importe=o.importe,descripcion=o.descripcion from @agendas o inner join dbo.[eventos publico] on ep0=o.id0
```

para actualizar registros en una tabla, eventos publico, usando ese tipo definido, agendas.

Y también

```
insert dbo.[eventos publico] (ep1,nombre,finicio,ffin,importe,descripcion) select @id0,que,finicio,ffin,importe,descripcion from @agendas o where id0=0
```

para insertar registros (donde la clave primaria -id0 que metí en el tipo agendas- es 0).

En mis páginas asp.net, junto con los registros que dejo que el usuario edite, mando la clave primaria de esos registros en un literal con visible a false.

Ahora quiero poner una sentencia sql para borrar los registros no añadidos (id0=0) o cuya clave primaria o id0 no esté en la tabla eventos publico (ya que el usuario de mis páginas asp.net los dio de baja) Se trata de borrar registros de un tipo de obra (ep1=@id0) que no estén en la tabla (el usuario los dio de baja) ni añadidos (id0=0)

Hago este alta, baja y modificación manualmente. Anteriormente lo que hacía era borrar todos los registros de esa ep1 y añadía todos los que el usuario editaba. Pero esta técnica me rompe la relación directa 
entre eventos publico y otra tabla, solicitudes invitaciones.

Puse esta sentencia de borrado

```
delete dbo.[eventos publico] where ep1=@id0 and ep0 in (select id0 from @agendas o where ep0=o.id0 and o.id0>0)
```

Pero no sirve (me borra todos los registros de esa ep1 -tipo de obra, los eventos publico son obras- excepto el que el usuario da de baja)

Quiero borrar de la tabla eventos publico. Los eventos publico editados no añadidos (id0=0) y editados pero dados de baja por el usuario (esto lo puedo saber a la hora de borrar los registros porque esa clave primaria lo ha dado de baja el usuario y ya no está en el tipo agendas)

¿Cómo invierto la condición IN?

Es eso lo que no sé, poner bien la subconsulta. No sé si debería hace un join.

La tabla eventos publico es

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[eventos publico](
[ep0] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ep1] [int] NOT NULL,
[nombre] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
[finicio] [date] NOT NULL,
[ffin] [date] NOT NULL,
[importe] [money] NOT NULL,
[descripcion] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
```

He probado a poner NOT IN con la misma delete. Entonces ya no me añade bien (id0=0).

Tengo que tener bien la actualización, inserción y borrado. Que funcionen juntas.

Si se les ocurre otra técnica para llevar a cabo lo mismo, estoy abierto.

He puesto esta sentencia delete

```
delete dbo.[eventos publico] from @agendas o left join dbo.[eventos publico] on ep0=o.id0 where ep1=@id0 and ep0 is null and id0>0
```

Con ella me respeta la adición (id0=0), actualización. Pero no me borra nada, no sé por qué. En teoría debería borrar los registros de eventos publico que no tiene correspondencia con agendas y aquellos cuya id0>0.

¿Cómo hacer?

Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Tu subconsulta va a entregar los registros que SÍ están en `agendas`. Tu consulta dice que borres lo que esté en `[eventos publico]` cuyo `ep0` ESTÉ en la subconsulta. Eso hace que borres lo que sí está en `agendas`. Necesitas invertir la condición `IN`, buscas lo que no está en `agendas` porque el usuario lo dio de baja o no lo añadió

Comment: Hola Martin para ayudarte requiero que me expliques de que tabla quieres borrar, basado en el criterio de que campo (veo que mencionas ep1=0) o algo así, si me muestras mas explicitamente te puedo ayudar con facilidad.

Comment: @Martin not in(consulta)